# Get original filename from zipped file

Tags: regex, perl

I have zipped files names like:

```
filename1.csv.Z
filename2.csv.gz
```

I have regex expression for getting the last extension:

```
my ($ext) = $file =~ /(\.[^.]+)$/;
```

Now I would like to get the "original filename", without .Z or .gz, eg. filename1.csv, filename2.csv

I tried to use something like expresion below but does not work...

```
my ($output) = $file =~ /.+?(?=(([^.]+)$))/;
```

Would anybody help me out?

Comment: If this is the match `\.[^.]+$` you could replace it with an empty string or use a capturing group `(.+?)\.[^.]+$`

Comment: Maybe it will suffice to remove the known suffix? `$file =~ s/\.(?:Z|gz)$//`?

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew `my ($output ) = $file =~ s/\.(?:Z|gz)$//; print $output ;` returns `1`. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: See [this demo](https://ideone.com/2jiEcJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your pattern `.+?(?=[^.]+$)` you assert what is directly on the right is 1+ times not a dot followed by the end of the string.

That assertion could be true at multiple places and will also include matching the dot itself.

For example in `filename2.csv.gz` that will match `filename2.csv.` and `g`

If you want to get the match only of the filename in the example data, you could add the dot in the positive lookahead:

```
.+(?=\.[^.]+$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SqY9GY/1)

Or use a capturing group and a match instead of a lookahead:

```
(.+)\.[^.]+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2sF0Fj/1) | [Perl demo](https://ideone.com/QNuVaL)

For example

```
my $line = "filename1.csv.Z";
my ($output) = $line =~ m/(.+)\.[^.]+$/;
print $output;

# filename1.csv
```

Answer (score 6):

Know your standard library. See [File::Basename](http://p3rl.org/File::Basename):

```
use File::Basename qw(basename);
for my $fullname (qw(filename1.csv.Z filename2.csv.gz)) {
    my $basename = basename $fullname, qw(.Z .gz);
}
__END__
filename1.csv
filename2.csv
```